# Code for converting long string to pass in URL

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to take a string like "Hello my name is Nick" and transform it to "Hello+my+name+is+Nick" to be passed through a URL. This would be easily done by replacing all the spaces with a + char however I also need to replace all special characters (. , ! &) with their ASCII values. I have searched the net but cannot find anything. I wonder if anyone knows of existing code to do this as its a fairly common task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for this: [HttpUtility.UrlEncode Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx)
Handles non-URL compliant characters and spaces.